# How to check whether variable is null or not in PHP

Tags: php, variables, null

In PHP,

I am using One Variable called $token.

I want to check whether it's value is null or not.I have tried by checking `empty/isset/is_null` in if condition.But It didn't work.

when I print its value using `error_log($token)` then it gives output like : "`(null)`".

Because in database its value is "`(null)`".

How can I check in php whether it is `(null)` or not.

Please guide me on this.

Comment: Check `var_dump($token)` and see what it is

Comment: Where's that value coming from? I would start by fixing the source so you can use a format that PHP can parse and understand.

Comment: it could be returning a string called " (null) ", as mentioned in 1st comment, var_dump would be helpful.

And if it is so, then you should follow the advice on comment 2 to check what is putting out the " (null) "

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you're working not with a real `null`, but with a string - that's literally `'(null)'`. So check for that instead, with...

```
if ($token === '(null)') { ... }
```

What's more important, however, is why this value appeared in the DB in first place. Unless there's a very specific (and valid) reason to do this, you'd better store nulls (absence of information) as plain `NULL` value, to avoid confusion such in this case both on application and database layer.

Answer (score 0):

What you did is also right. 
Even You can have some more options
**try following conditions**

```
1. if($token === null){....}
2. if($token == null){....}
3. if($token == ""){....}
```

1. init some a string variable

   $tmp_string = "";
   $tmp_string .= $token
   if($tmp_string== ""){....}

Try All above. 
All The Best....

Answer (score 0):

or the shortest way

```
if($token) echo 'not null';
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem using `strlen() condition`.Thank you all for your suggestions.

Comment: strlen($token)  ,If it is divisible by 16(which is property of iphone device token) then I can do what I want.